# Is the Mysql using "_" in DB creation have special meanings?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a DB called:
MY_XXXX and MY_YYYY.

When I go to the phpMyAdmin, it shows in the tree structure...like this:
[image]

So, my questions is, is the MySQL or the phpMyAdmin do this things for me...? Is this have some special meaning for that? Thank you.

Comment: phpmyadmin does this for you, it has no special meaning

Comment: I've just tried (with MySql console) to create a database named my_xxxx and then run SHOW DATABASES: db name is still the one I gave it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is phpMyAdmin making a (sort of reasonable-ish, a bit, actually largely un-warranted) assumption about a naming convention - it's *nothing* to do with MySQL.

If your looking for more information on such things - see the MySQL [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) documentation. (As you'll see - it defines no special meaning to the underscore other than stating that it's considered a valid character.)

Answer (score 0):

THis means you have multiple databases starting with **MY** .

So rather then showing showing it in different headings as MY_1, MY_2 phpMyAdmin shows them as

```
MY_
    1
    2
```

etc.